# How do you display the contents of one cell to another in excel?

Tags: excel

I want to display the contents in column a in column b.

Comment: this is basics of excel: put `42` into `A1` then put `=A1` into `B1`

Comment: Might need Scott Craner for this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fx `=(cell_reference)`

when u do that in column a, drag it down for as many rows as needed.

fx `=transpose(cell_array_reference)`

choose the starting cell then ":" then the last row you want. This will auto list them swapping the row and column position.

Answer (score 0):

Enter "=" then click the cell who's content you wand displayed. Hit enter.

Once it's working for the first cell, grab the little indicator in the corner of the cell and drag it down to do the same thing for the entire column.